# FFMPEG not writing quicktime "COLR" atom

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime

I am attempting to create Quicktime movs with the "DNXHD" codec with the following ffmpeg command (input part excluded):

```
-c:v dnxhd -b:v 175M -pix_fmt yuv422p10le test.mov
```

This works, and is displayed fine in After Effects and Premiere.  However, it does not play back correctly in Quicktime Player - it looks slightly "washed out".  My understanding of this is that Quicktime Player uses the "COLR" atom to determine the color space of the video file for playback.  So, after some research I came upon this ffmpeg option:

```
-movflags +write_colr
```

But, it doesn't seem to do anything.  Analyzing the video with "exiftool" shows that the atom was not written.

I am using FFMPEG version 2.8.6, installed with homebrew on Mac OS 10.11.3.

Anyone know how to make ffmpeg's movs comply with Quicktime Player's expectations?

Answer (score 1):

That is an experimental flag, so you will have to use

```
-movflags +write_colr -strict experimental
```

Comment: Thank you!  That seems to work with all the codecs I try EXCEPT dnxhd.  Any ideas?  My command: `-c:v dnxhd -b:v 175M -strict experimental -movflags +write_colr`

Comment: Which is strange since the only codec it is meant for is DNxHD 1080I 120M. But the strict flag should force it elsewhere. Are you seeing the COLR atom created with other codecs? Use atomicparsely to check atoms.

Comment: AtomicParsely seems not to like Quicktime files.  exiftool works though.  The output to look out for from exiftool is `Color Representation            : nclc 1 1 1`

Comment: I can't seem to get ffmpeg to write this atom at all when using "dnxhd".  It does work with "prores_ks".  How did you get it to work with dnxhd?

Comment: Check the playback in Quicktime, or ffprobe readout for the DNxHD output. Mediainfo reports color space characteristics ( prims, matrix..etc) that it doesn't when encoded without the color flag.

Comment: From ffprobe: `Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 176160 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 12288 tbc (default)`

Comment: The colorspace is recorded `bt709`. How's the playback in QT?

Comment: Looks "washed out" in QT, looks fine elsewhere.

Comment: All the colr atom [function](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/movenc.c#L1567) does is set the three color related variables, to bt709 in case of HD.  But that's already done in your case. So, try setting the gamma atom as well. Use `-movflags +write_colr+write_gama -strict experimental`

Comment: Only for QT playback, use `-c:v dnxhd -b:v 175M -src_range 0 -dst_range 1 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -movflags +write_colr -strict experimental test.mov`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is not really a solution.  I want the movie to be rendered correctly for usage in any application, and also be viewable with correct colors in Quicktime Player.

Comment: Looks like DNxHD relies on the [ACLR](http://community.avid.com/forums/p/133583/761319.aspx#761319), not the COLR, atom. And ffmpeg does seem to [write it](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/movenc.c#L1053) correctly. I think the issue here is with your source, for which I have no details.